# R: Multiplying columns by a constant in a data table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to correct my data table so my columns have the same units. Here's an example of what I have.

```
hh:mm   A   V   W   kA  V   kW  A   kV  kW
11:00   13.84   470.16  6509.88 14.89   467.85  6964.38 15.74   464.01  7303.13
11:05   12.54   475.17  5959.22 13.40   474.52  6358.89 13.34   473.13  6311.80
11:10   9.73    476.20  4632.14 10.36   473.38  4905.86 10.38   472.73  4907.14
11:15   9.20    479.30  4410.89 9.65    482.79  4659.67 9.73    479.09  4659.33
11:20   11.28   482.22  5437.78 12.03   484.95  5835.33 12.24   476.36  5829.44
11:25   11.66   481.64  5614.56 12.76   479.95  6124.56 12.88   476.86  6139.33
11:30   10.38   475.13  4934.00 11.99   480.96  5760.44 11.50   478.77  5515.13
```

As you can see, some columns are in "A","V", or "W", while others are in "kA","kV" or "kW". What I am trying to do is to change all these to the same units by multiplying the "kA", "kV" and "kW" columns by 1000. Here's what I want to get

```
hh:mm   A   V   W   A   V   W   A   V   W
11:00   13.84   470.16  6509.88 14890   467.85  6964380 15.74   464010  7303130
11:05   12.54   475.17  5959.22 13400   474.52  6358890 13.34   473130  6311800
11:10   9.73    476.20  4632.14 10360   473.38  4905860 10.38   472730  4907140
11:15   9.20    479.30  4410.89 9650    482.79  4659670 9.73    479090  4659330
11:20   11.28   482.22  5437.78 12030   484.95  5835330 12.24   476360  5829440
11:25   11.66   481.64  5614.56 12760   479.95  6124560 12.88   476860  6139330
11:30   10.38   475.13  4934.00 11990   480.96  5760440 11.50   478770  5515130
```

I tried doing this:

```
units<-which(names(dt)=="kA") # Gives me a vector with the positions needed.
dt[,units:=units*1000] #Multiplies the vector by 1000
names(dt) <- gsub("kA", "A", names(dt)) # Changes "kA" to "A"

units<-which(names(dt)=="kV") # Gives me a vector with the positions needed.
dt[,units:=units*1000] #Multiplies the vector by 1000
names(dt) <- gsub("kV", "V", names(dt)) # Changes "kV" to "V"

units<-which(names(dt)=="kW") # Gives me a vector with the positions needed.
dt[,units:=units*1000] #Multiplies the vector by 1000
names(dt) <- gsub("kW", "W", names(dt)) # Changes "kW" to "W"
```

On my second line, I receive this error:

```
Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(x2, , `:=`(units, units * 1000)) :
  Supplied 48 items to be assigned to 286 items of column 'units' (recycled leaving remainder of 46 items).
```

Can anyone help me with my syntax please?

PS: Here's my dput for the input, it looks a little funny though.

```
> dput(c)
structure(list(`hh:mm` = c("11:00", "11:05", "11:10", "11:15", 
"11:20", "11:25", "11:30"), A = c(13.84, 12.54, 9.73, 9.2, 11.28, 
11.66, 10.38), V = c(470.16, 475.17, 476.2, 479.3, 482.22, 481.64, 
475.13), W = c(6509.88, 5959.22, 4632.14, 4410.89, 5437.78, 5614.56, 
4934), kA = c(14.89, 13.4, 10.36, 9.65, 12.03, 12.76, 11.99), 
    V = c(467.85, 474.52, 473.38, 482.79, 484.95, 479.95, 480.96
    ), kW = c(6964.38, 6358.89, 4905.86, 4659.67, 5835.33, 6124.56, 
    5760.44), A = c(15.74, 13.34, 10.38, 9.73, 12.24, 12.88, 
    11.5), kV = c(464.01, 473.13, 472.73, 479.09, 476.36, 476.86, 
    478.77), kW = c(7303.13, 6311.8, 4907.14, 4659.33, 5829.44, 
    6139.33, 5515.13)), .Names = c("hh:mm", "A", "V", "W", "kA", 
"V", "kW", "A", "kV", "kW"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000003b0788>)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't really using `data.table` correctly. Here is one approach that can be used:

```
DT[, c("A2", "W2", "V2") := lapply(.SD, function(x) x*1000), .SDcols=c("kA", "kW", "kV")]
DT[, c("kA", "kW", "kV") := NULL]
DT
#    hh.mm     A      V       W    V.1   A.1    kW.1    A2      W2     V2
# 1: 11:00 13.84 470.16 6509.88 467.85 15.74 7303.13 14890 6964380 464010
# 2: 11:05 12.54 475.17 5959.22 474.52 13.34 6311.80 13400 6358890 473130
# 3: 11:10  9.73 476.20 4632.14 473.38 10.38 4907.14 10360 4905860 472730
# 4: 11:15  9.20 479.30 4410.89 482.79  9.73 4659.33  9650 4659670 479090
# 5: 11:20 11.28 482.22 5437.78 484.95 12.24 5829.44 12030 5835330 476360
# 6: 11:25 11.66 481.64 5614.56 479.95 12.88 6139.33 12760 6124560 476860
# 7: 11:30 10.38 475.13 4934.00 480.96 11.50 5515.13 11990 5760440 478770
```

A few things to note:

- Your current solution has you creating a `data.table` with duplicated names. Bad practice. I made the mistake of not converting one of your columns here, but I'll leave that exercise of updating the answer to you.
- If you are going to use `data.table`, get familiar with the `set*` set of functions.

---

Alternatively using `set`:

```
cols <- grep("^k", names(dt))
for (j in cols) {
    set(DT, i=NULL, j=j, value=DT[[j]]*1000)
}
# change names with `setnames` now.
setnames(DT, cols, gsub("^k", "", names(dt)[cols])
```

Although I agree with @Ananda on not using duplicate names.

Comment: I was literally about to suggest `cols <- names(dt)[ grepl( "k" , names(dt) ) ];dt[ , lapply( .SD , \`*\` , 1000 ) , .SDcols = cols  , by = eval( names(dt)[ ! names(dt) %in% cols ] ) ]`

Comment: Also methinks you should have used `check.names = FALSE` when using `read.table`... :-)

Comment: @SimonO101, I didn't even notice that second `kW`. Bad practice by the OP. I like your solution to sort of "automate" things though.

Comment: Unfortunately mine won't quite work due to the duplicated column names in the data.table. I have asked a question on this now.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the repeated columns. The reason why I had it there on purpose was that the actual raw csv has 3 headers, and 1 of them happen to be units. (1st header contains serial numbers, second header contains name of parameters like Voltage, current and power among others, 3rd headers are units). By standardising the units for each parameter, I am able to eliminate one header. (I will concert another header to factors next) That's why there are repeated columns.

Comment: Also, thank you for your example. I now understand exactly how to use a function in data.table

Comment: @Arun Strange to see "I agree with @Ananda" in Ananda's answer :) Anyway, +1 for a joint effort leading to the use of `set`.