# Can data.table handle identical column names when using .SDcols?

Tags: r, syntax, data.table

When using `.SD` to apply a function to a subset of `dt`'s columns I can't seem to find the correct way to handle the situation where I have duplicated column names... e.g.

```
#  Make some data
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table( matrix( sample(6,16,repl=T) , 4 ) )
setnames(dt , rep( letters[1:2] , 2 ) )
#   a b a b
#1: 2 6 4 5
#2: 5 1 3 4
#3: 3 4 6 1
#4: 6 6 3 6

#  Use .SDcols to multiply both column 'a' specifying them by numeric position
dt[ , lapply( .SD , `*`  , 2 ) , .SDcols = which( names(dt) %in% "a" ) ]
#    a  a
#1:  4  4
#2: 10 10
#3:  6  6
#4: 12 12
```

I couldn't get it to work with when `.SDcols` was a character vector of column names so I tried numeric positions (`which( names(dt) %in% "a" )` gives a vector `[1] 1 3` ) but it also seems to just multiply the first `a` column only. Am I doing something wrong?

> **`.SDcols`** *Advanced. Specifies the columns of x included in .SD. May be character column names or numeric positions.*

These also returned the same result as above...

```
dt[ , lapply( .SD ,function(x) x*2 ) , .SDcols = which( names(dt) %in% "a" ) ]
dt[ , lapply( .SD ,function(x) x*2 ) , .SDcols = c(1,3) ]

packageVersion("data.table")
#[1] ‘1.8.11’
```

Comment: [See here](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/datatable-help/2013-November/002198.html) for on-going discussion on this topic and [here for the bug filed by @Ricardo](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5008&group_id=240&atid=975)

Comment: Is this just playing around or do you have a reason for duplicated names? If it's the latter, please contribute to the post Arun mentioned.

Comment: @eddi in response to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19809168/1478381)

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
dt[, "a"] * 2
##    a a.1
## 1  4   8
## 2 10   6
## 3  6  12
## 4 12   6
```

For more detailed discussion

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/12783493#12783493

Comment: It's not really answering the question. I am asking specifically about using `.SDcols` but thanks.

Comment: @SimonO101 I think that's the way .SD and .SDcols coded. There has been discussion about this on data.table mailing list recently

Comment: Even when using numeric positions of columns?

Comment: So it turns out that it can't be done. +1 for the workaround though.

Answer (score 1):

#### This now works as intended since 1.9.4.  From NEWS:

> Consistent subset rules on `data.tables` with duplicate columns. In short, if indices are directly provided, 'j', or in `.SDcols`, then just those columns are either returned (or deleted if you provide -`.SDcols` or `!j`). If instead, column names are given and there are more than one occurrence of that column, then it's hard to decide which to keep and which to remove on a subset. Therefore, to remove, all occurrences of that column are removed, and to keep, always the first column is returned each time. Also closes [#5688](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/86) and [#5008](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/22). Note that using `by=` to aggregate on duplicate columns may not give intended result still, as it may not operate on the proper column.

Basically, if you do:

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, `*`, 2), .SDcols=c("a", "a")]
#     a  a
# 1:  4  4
# 2: 10 10
# 3:  6  6
# 4: 12 12
```

It'll still give the unintended result, as it's hard to tell which "a" you're mentioning each time - so choosing the first always.

But if you clearly specify (as you do in your Q):

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, `*`, 2), .SDcols=which( names(dt) %in% "a" )]
#     a  a
# 1:  4  8
# 2: 10  6
# 3:  6 12
# 4: 12  6
```